# Google Drive Image URL Thumbnail Expires After a Few Hours

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

I am using Google Picker to integrate Google Drive into my web CMS.

Everything looks great, users can select which images they want to link to their contents, then the image thumbnail url provided by Picker is grabbed to store into a DB.

The problem is that after a few hours that thumbnail URL provided by Picker expires leading to a 403 message (Your client does not have permission to get URL ..). This does not happens with imagenes extarcted from PICASA (Google Photos) where the image link is long lasting or never expires

Is there a way to get a fixed/non-perishable URL out of Google Picker for images thumbnails?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible for google drive unless you upload a thumbnail image yourself and use the download link.